# View drawRect only called after delay

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I made a `UIView` subclass that implements custom drawing. Here is the code (please don't mind that this could be done by a `UIImageView`. I stripped the code of all extras just to show the problem)

```
@IBDesignable
class TPMSkinnedImageView: UIView {
    private var originalImage:UIImage?
    private var skinnedImage:UIImage?

    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        set {
            originalImage = newValue

            if(newValue == nil) {
                skinnedImage = nil
                return
            }

            skinnedImage = originalImage!

            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }

        get {
            return originalImage
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context:CGContext! = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context.saveGState()
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: rect.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        context.draw(skinnedImage!.cgImage!, in: rect)
        context.restoreGState()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        if(skinnedImage != nil) {
            return skinnedImage!.size
        }

        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

I instantiate this view in a viewcontroller nib file and show the viewcontroller modally.

What happens is is that the `draw` method only gets called when the parent view has been on screen for about 20 seconds.

I checked the `intrinsicContentSize` and it does not return `.zero`

This is what the stack looks like once it is called:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `setNeedsDisplay()`  on your view in your view controller's `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: I called it on the subview itself and it works. But I don't understand why I should do this. Normally my view shouldn't be aware of the fact that there are subviews with custom drawing code. It should draw it at least once when the view is shown, I would think.

Comment: Not sure. Set a breakpoint in your draw method and see when it's called. Look at the stack trace to see where it gets called from.